# Find if an array contains a string with one mismatch

Tags: python, performance, coding-efficiency

I want say there is a string in the list with only one mismatch

```
def check(list, s):
    n = len(list)
 
    # If the array is empty
    if (n == 0):
        return False
 
    for i in range(0, n, 1):
         
        # If sizes are same
        if (len(list[i]) != len(s)):
            continue
 
        diff = False
        for j in range(0, len(list[i]), 1):
            if (list[i][j] != s[j]):
 
                # If first mismatch
                if (diff == False):
                    diff = True
 
                # Second mismatch
                else:
                    diff = False
                    break
                 
        if (diff):
            return True
 
    return False
```

This code is okay but it works slowly. How can I make it faster using a dictionary?

Comment: As an aside, it is not a good idea to mask the names of the standard Python types (e.g., `list`, `dict`, `str`, etc.), even in a function which never refers to the types by name.

Comment: I'm not certain if hashing the strings would actually help, I suppose it depends in part on the hash function (not all would be useful for this type of comparison, and those which are are unlikely to be faster than a brute-force comparison), and in part on the actual goal. What are you matching the strings for? How long are the strings you are trying to match? For very long strings, a more powerful [string-searching algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-searching_algorithm) may be called for.

Comment: Not all such algorithms would be suited for this particular comparison, however.

Answer (score 0):

You can use zip() to pair up each character of two strings and sum() to count the number of mismatches.  The any() function will allow you to check for a match over every item in the list:

```
def check(sList,string):
    return any(len(string)==len(s) and sum(a!=b for a,b in zip(s,string))==1 
               for s in sList)

check(["abcd","cdef","efgh"],"xfgh") # True
check(["abcd","cdef","efgh"],"abdc") # False
```

This translates to the following basic for-loop:

```
def check(sList,string):
    for s in sList:
        if len(string) !=len(s): continue
        if sum(a!=b for a,b in zip(s,string)) == 1:
            return True
    return False
```

[EDIT] to make this go a bit faster, the string comparisons can use zip() as an iterator so that the comparison doesn't need to go to the end of every string:

```
def check(sList,string):
    for s in sList:
        if len(string) !=len(s): continue
        mismatch = (a!=b for a,b in zip(s,string))  # non-matching iterator
        if not any(mismatch): continue              # at least one
        if any(mismatch): continue                  # no more after that
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: It is not fast enough. I should check many string. Total length of strings is 10^6 and every test should run in 3 sec